# Derivative of $\sqrt{x^2+1}$

Tags: derivatives

Ive been given this rule and asked to differentiate $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, however I am not sure what I am missing.It is said that if f is differentiable at x and f(x)>0.

$\frac{d}{\text{dx}}$$\sqrt{f(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{2 \sqrt{f(x)}}$

What I thought would be correct is that:

$\frac{d}{\text{dx}}$$\sqrt{x^2+1}$ = $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x^2+1}}$,

However in the textbook the answer is:

$\frac{x}{ \sqrt{x^2+1}}$

I do not get how this square rule is made, and why $f'(x)$ is in the numerator.

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: You are missing the $f'(x)$ in your computation...

Comment: Yes, but it is done without the chain rule apparently.

Comment: Yes but I do not understand the steps, I am able to read the formula but how is it derived?

Comment: Also, the answer does not have a ${ 1 \over 2} $ factor.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The square root rule is a consequence of the power rule, with power $n=1/2$. Now, i see you are confused because ${\mathrm d\over\mathrm dx}\sqrt{x+1}={1\over2\sqrt{x+1}}$ and ${\mathrm d\over\mathrm dx}\sqrt{x^2+1}={x\over\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ . POWER RULE PROOF: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Rule_for_Derivatives

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly why I am confused, can you take the last derivative in a step by step so that I see how its done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derive using the chain rule and the rule for polynomials: 
$$ f(x) =\sqrt{x^2+1} = (x^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}},$$ then $$ f'(x) =\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot(2x) = x\cdot(x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} =\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=(\sqrt{x^2+1})'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}(x^2+1)'=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Your first part is correct but you need to apply the chain rule, since you are differentiating $\sqrt{g(x)}$ not $\sqrt{x}$. There's a function under the square root instead of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

set
$$
w = x^2 + 1 \\
y = \sqrt{w} = w^\frac12
$$
so:
$$
\frac{dy}{dw} = \frac12 w^{-\frac12}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{dw}{dx} = 2x
$$
now use the *chain rule*
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dw} \times \frac{dw}{dx}
$$